# Denied Permissions to access and move folder from a Mac Hard Disk

Tags: nautilus, hard-drive, permissions, mac

I have a iMac in which the Hard disk has failed. **I am trying to get files off the users desktop that has not been backed up.** I cannot repair the Hard disk and do not have another Mac to transfer the data over that way.

I am using the live version of ubuntu from the CD. The Mac drive is there and I can access it, but I cannot access the users desktop, music and pictures folders. It gives me "no Permissions" message. When I right click on the folder, all the options are grayed out.

I have an external hard disk attached to the Mac and I want to move the content onto the External Hard Drive. I have tried using the `chown` command but I am struggling with it at the moment as I am not sure who to put in at the "username" part. I have tried using `gksudo nautilus` but I still don't have permissions to change the owner of the folder.

Comment: This has been resolved. After using gksudo nautilus again I was able to access the folders and copy the data over to the external HD

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer for future searchers

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution that worked for me.

Open the terminal and use:

```
gksudo nautilus
```

That bypasses the permissions and I was able to copy/paste the data to an external.

Answer (score 0):

This has been resolved. After using gksudo nautilus again I was able to access the folders and copy the data over to the external HD – **Oliver Aug 1 '13 at 9:27**